# Convert Image to WebP using ImageProcessor

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, imageprocessor

I used this code to convert uploaded images to `WebP` format in asp.net core:

```
        using (var webPFileStream = new FileStream(webpImagePath, FileMode.Create))
        {                
            using (var imageFactory = new ImageFactory(preserveExifData: false))
            {
                imageFactory.Load(file.OpenReadStream())
                            .Format(new WebPFormat())
                            .Quality(100)
                            .Save(webPFileStream);
            }
        }
```

It works fine locally. But after hosting, it gives me error message "cannot load libwebp.dll". I couldn't find any solution on stackoverflow and couldn't figure if it's the host or the package.

Answer (score 0):

According this [article](https://imageprocessor.org/imageprocessor/plugins/webp/), please make sure you have installed below things.

Requires msvcr120.dll from the Visual C++ Redistributable Package for Visual Studio 2013 to be installed on the server.

If you are using version 1.0.2 or lower it instead requires msvcr110.dll from the Visual C++ Redistributable Package for Visual Studio 2012 to be installed.

Comment: I don't have control over the server.

Comment: Please connect the server admin to make sure installing these things. Other than it will not work.